# Call the same HTTP service with different page number parameters in Angular and RxJS 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-observables, rxjs6

Ok so here is the context.

Consider an e-commerce category page which loads products as **Infinite Scroll**.

Now as the user scrolls down, we change the query params to page=2 and we call the http service to load products of page 2 and then similiar process for page 3 and so on.

Now say the user is on page 3 and he clicks on a product, which takes him to the product detail component. And from there he clicks on the **browser's back button**.

So now he comes back to the category component with query param page=3, and the component makes the http call for page 3 onInit.

What I want to do is, that after the products for page 3 are loaded, I want to make the same call again for page=2 and on success of that make the third call for page=1.

On each call, I want to load the products of page 2 and page 1 on top of the page 3 products obviously.

My HTTP call looks like this:

```
this._categoryService.get(
        this.categoryId,
        this.currentPage - 1,
        this.pageSize,
        sorting.sort,
        sorting.order,
        this._filterService.getFilter().getValue()
 ).subscribe(res => {
     if(this.pagination.type === 'standard' || this.items.length === 0){
       this.totalCount = res.total;
       this.items = res.data;
       this.filter = [...res.filter];
     }else{
       this.totalCount = res.total;
       this.items.push(...res.data);
       this.filter = [...res.filter];
     }
      });
```

So what I am doing on the success call back is to check that if the item's list is empty, just assign the response data to the array.

But if it is not empty, I am pushing the values to the already existing array.

I want to know, what is the proper way of doing this in rxJS 6. Is there an obvious operator that I can use to call page 3, then page 2 and then page 1, subsequently on each success callback?

Also, what is the best way to **prepend (Append before/Unshift)** the products on the items array?

**Please note, I have not yet implemented this, because I don't want to chain HTTP calls inside subscribe for obvious reasons.**

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS**

The infinite scroll will be applied only if products are less in number. Say for example maximum 10 pages of products.

If there are more, the category page will have normal pagination.

I am using both ngx-paginate and ngx-infinite-scroll for this project.

Comment: To sum up : you have an infinite scroll, but it only works one way, not the other ? What happens if you're on page 687 ? Do you load the 686 previous pages ?

Comment: Yes so basically it should first load 687, and the load the previous ones subsequently and add them above the already present list of products. If that makes sense?

Comment: Yes it does, do you understand that the user's computer might die of slowness with this solution ? What's the purpose of using an infinite scroll if you load every page like this ?

Comment: Why is it important that the subsequent request finishes? Couldn't you just do all the requests and wait until all of them finish? That would save you a lot of time.

Comment: @trichetriche the client's service does not cater that if I load page=687, it sends me all the products of the previous pages as well. So I have to manage this from the front-end

Comment: @MichaelKie this is because as trichetriche said, if the user is on page 687, and if I load all at once, you can imagine how load the user is gonna wait

Comment: @trichetriche also to add to the context, I can switch between normal pagination and infinite scroll. So if there is page 687, the user will get normal pagination. That is what pagination.type === 'standard' means in this case

Comment: That's twisted. Why don't you simply put a virtual scroll on the other way : if the user reaches the top of the current page, it loads the previous page ? This would save you lots of time, code and complexity ...

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. So basically what you are saying is that just like bottom scroll, I do the same on top scroll also?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying : use your infinite scrolling to its full potential !

Comment: I also think thats the better solution to your specific problem. If you still want to do Observable chaining check out [concatAll](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concatall.html) for synchronous and [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) for asynchronous operations.

Comment: Ok I need to see if I can do that using ngx-infinte-scroll. Can I keep you guys updated?

Comment: Sure, I recommend you keep this question opened, and if you face an issue related to HTTP calls, you update it, but if you face an infinite scroll issue, you create a new question and notify us (well, me at least) there

Comment: @MichaelKie sure I will look at that too. Let me try out the reverse scroll as suggested first. If somehow I cannot achieve this, I will try the Operators you mentioned.

Comment: @trichetriche affirmative. Thank you so much both of you :)

Comment: @trichetrice Are you available?

Comment: @MichaelKie Are you available?